# Not Displaying Date And Time for Updating In a Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model, razor-pages

This is my model:
attributes of Appointment that is Appdate and Apptime

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime AppDate { get; set; }
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime AppTime { get; set; }
```

And I have some data in the database which I want to show for to update Appointment but its not showing

```
  <div class="input">
        <label asp-for="AppDate">Date Of Appointment:</label>
        <input asp-for="AppDate" value="@Model.AppDate" type="date" />
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label asp-for="AppTime">Date of Time:</label>
        <input asp-for="AppTime" value="@Model.AppTime" type="time" />
    </div>
```

This is my cshtml file's some part the given model is not empty its rendering data just not displaying it as in view source page after I view the update cshtml this is what the date its rendering

```
<div class="input">
        <label for="AppDate">Date Of Appointment:</label>
        <input value="30/08/2023 12:00:00 am" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The AppDate field is required." id="AppDate" name="AppDate" />  
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="AppTime">Date of Time:</label>
        <input value="21/08/2023 11:15:00 pm" type="time" data-val="true" data-val-required="The AppTime field is required." id="AppTime" name="AppTime" />
    </div>
```

And note `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]`
This has not helped in my database it still saving date and time both in default format

This is what I have tried

```
@Html.TextBoxfor(m=>m.Appdate,"{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")
```

This has not worked as its not displaying the calendar input style for proper input and also after clicking submit button its not saving in database correctly.

Then I tried using this instead

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AppDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @type = "date" })
```

But it again rendering data and not showing in the cshtml page this is the view source page code of the cshtml

```
<div class="input">
        <label for="AppDate">Date Of Appointment:</label>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The AppDate field is required." id="AppDate" name="AppDate" type="date" value="30/08/2023" />
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="AppTime">Date of Time:</label>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The AppTime field is required." id="AppTime" name="AppTime" type="time" value="11:15 pm" />
    </div>
```

I have also think of using

`<input value="@Model.AppDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" type="date" ...>`

But it doesn't work as it on submit button it will give input datatype error

Comment: Hello, your issue hasn't been clearly described because it was completely unreadable, would you kindly format your code snippet and explain what you are trying to achieve? You can check [`how to format code block here`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the value of the date and time inputs by specifying it directly. Consequently, the format string you specify in the `DisplayFormat` attribute is ignored:

```
<input asp-for="AppDate" value="@Model.AppDate" type="date" />
```

With input tag helpers, you should not need to set the `value` or the `type` attribute values. You should let the tag helper read the metadata from the model and generate the HTML for you:

```
<input asp-for="AppDate" />
```

That is all that is needed. The same applies to your `AppTime` input.